# how to print a javascript function to a pug file with node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have created a node app using express and a pug file. The express app called and listen on port 3000 and renders the pug file. I have a function which picks up information from an api and I would like to be able to use this information and print it using the pug file.

Here is my app.js file

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express') 
const app = express();
const pug = require('pug');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.render('index');
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.error = err;
  res.status(err.status);
 res.render('error');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('The application is running on localhost:3000!')
});
```

Here is the function I would like to get information from to be used in the pug file.

```
const printWeather = (weather) => {

    let message =`The weather in ${weather.location.city} is currently ${weather.current_observation.weather}`;
    message += ` Current temperature is ${weather.current_observation.temp_c}C`;
    message += ` It currently feels like ${weather.current_observation.feelslike_c}C`;
    message += ` The wind speed is currently ${weather.current_observation.wind_mph}mph`;
    message += ` The UV is currently ${weather.current_observation.UV}`;
    message += ` The humidity is currently ${weather.current_observation.relative_humidity}`;
    message += ` The wind direction is currently in the ${weather.current_observation.wind_dir}`;
    message += ` The pressure is currently ${weather.current_observation.pressure_mb}hPa`;
    message += ` The idibility is currently ${weather.current_observation.visibility_km}km`;
}

function get(query){
    const readableQuery = query.replace('_', ' ');
    try {
        const request = https.get(`https://api.wunderground.com/api/${api.key}/geolookup/conditions/q/${query}.json`, response => {
            if(response.statusCode === 200){
                let body = "";
                response.on('data', chunk => {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                response.on('end', () => {
                    try{
                        const weather = JSON.parse(body);
                        if (weather.location){
                            printWeather(weather);
                        } else {
                            const queryError = new Error(`The location "${readableQuery}" was not found.`);
                            printError(queryError);
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        printError(error);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                const statusCodeError = new Error(`There was an error getting the message for ${readableQuery}. (${http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode]})`);
                printError(statusCodeError);
            }
        });
```

Here is the pug file.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Weather App
  body
    h1 Weather App
    h2 #{message}
```

I can't seem to get the information to display from the pug file.

If you would like to see any more of my code please let me know.

I know this maybe isn't the best way to create and run my app but I am a beginner with node, express and pug and this is just me trying to learn some code on my own.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the function's output in the rendered page?

Comment: Where are you getting the `weather` parameter from? Where in `app.js` are you rendering this pug file?

Comment: yes Aron that is right, I'm a bit new to all this.

Comment: I updated my code in the question

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to do something like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  // this assumes that `getWeather` returns a promise or is an async function
  getWeather(req)
    .then(weather => {

      // make sure the `printWeather` function actually returns the message
      const message = printWeather(weather);
      res.render('index', { message });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? Does your `getWeather` function return a promise that resolves with the weather object? Does your `printWeather` function return a message string?

Comment: If I place a console.log(message); inside the printWeather function it prints the correct information

Comment: Sorry I can't help you debug. If you make sure that your code follows the requirements in my comment above things should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

`render` takes a second parameter that accepts data to be passed to the view:

```
const get = (query, res, req) => {

  // your query code... not shown to save space

  // lets start from inside the try block where you parse the body
  const weather = JSON.parse(body);
  // now instead of calling printWeather(weather);
  // you need to take the json data from the api call
  // and pass this json to the view
  if (weather.location) {
    res.render('index', { weather: weather, error: null } /* passed to index.pug */)
  } else {
    res.render('index', { weather: null, error: `the location was not found.` } /* passed to index.pug */)
  }
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  get(`enter_a_query_here`, req, res);
})
```

Then you can use this data in index.pug.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Weather App
  body
    h1 Weather App
    h2 Data: #{weather.current_observation.weather}
    p Error: #{error}
```

[Using Template Engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: This all well and fine but doesn't print the information from the function that I want

Comment: So you know how to send data to pug, then what is the problem?  Post a link to your code repo if possible.

Comment: I want to help. Can you show how you are sending data from express to pug?

Comment: Javascript functions are not 'printed' to pug.  You are having trouble with how data is passed to pug, like i posted above.  I will update my response to show how it applies to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, It hasn't worked but I will keep trying

Comment: console.log your errors. We cannot help you if we don't know where in the code you are having trouble.

Comment: I have changed my project to use jQuery as it worked much better, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: so the data are not delivered by your own server?
do you execute the javascript clientside? 
if so, then you had to add the information with jquery to the html document. 
if you have your own webserver, where you deliver your data, you can add it with the variable to the document.

As far as i see is, that you try to connect to an external API, which isnt programmed by you and do not deliver the pug. you deliver the pug which is nearly empty and execute the query, this will not work, because the pug has to be genereated by nodejs with local available data.